# Expand Rows in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table financial_installment like this:

```
INITIAL_DATE         Quantity     Value     Total
10/10/2020               3        100.0     300.0
```

How query this to get this result:

```
 10/10/2020  -   100.00   
 10/11/2020  -   100.00
 10/12/2020  -   100.00
```

Date between installment is one month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
select t.initial_date + make_interval(months => g.i::int) as the_date,
       value
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(1, t.quantity) as g(i)
order by 1
```